# The PowerShell -and conditional operator

Tags: powershell

Either I do not understand the documentation on MSDN or the documentation is incorrect.

```
if($user_sam -ne "" -and $user_case -ne "")
{
    Write-Host "Waaay! Both vars have values!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "One or both of the vars are empty!"
}
```

I hope you understand what I am attempting to output. I want to populate $user_sam and $user_case in order to access the first statement!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can simplify it to

```
if ($user_sam -and $user_case) {
  ...
}
```

because empty strings coerce to `$false` (and so does `$null`, for that matter).

Answer (score 10):

Another option:

```
if( ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($user_sam) -and ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($user_case) )
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try like this:

```
if($user_sam -ne $NULL -and $user_case -ne $NULL)
```

Empty variables are `$null` and then different from "" (`[string]::empty`).

Answer (score 5):

The code that you have shown **will** do what you want iff those properties equal "" when they are not filled in. If they equal $null when not filled in for example, then they will not equal "". Here is an example to prove the point that what you have will work for "":

```
$foo = 1
$bar = 1
$foo -eq 1 -and $bar -eq 1
True
$foo -eq 1 -and $bar -eq 2
False
```